Make city address attribute as optional per website | Magento 2
By default customer address attribute "city" is set as required. I would like to make "city" address attribute optional per website. When I access configuration page in magento admin and try to change "Values required" configuration to "No" on website scope, it is not possible.
"Values required" field is in global scope and I am not able to make "city" field as optional in customer address on website scope.
How can this be done?
Thank you all in advance!

In Magento 2, the city address attribute is required by default. However, if you want to make the city field optional on a per-website basis, you’ll need to customize Magento’s behavior.

Yes I am aware of that, unfortunately that was not a question if there is a need to customize behavior or not. In the meantime I fixed it by customizing code.
